# TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3

Tags: python

I'm making a small guessing game in Python where the computer guesses a number chosen by the player. I'm getting an error when I try to ask for user input:

```
answer = input("Is it", guess, "?")
```

This line throws

> TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Related: [How do I put a variable inside a String in Python?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2960772)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`input` only accepts *one* argument, you are passing it 3. You need to use string formatting or concatenation to make it one argument:

```
answer = input(f"Is it {guess} ?")
```

You were confusing this with the `print()` function, which does indeed take more than one argument and will concatenate the values into one string for you.