# Unable to get incrementing counter variable in input output statment

Tags: python, for-loop, user-input, nested-loops, python-3.3

I'm attempting utilizing TeamTreehouse learning subscription & this Starting Out With Programming Logic And Design book to attempt learning programming & python. Please don't shoot to kill me I'm having difficulty with repetition structures!

Goal: I'm attempting to collect input from a user in the outer for loop. The inner loop will iterate 12 times per outer loop iteration calculating; getting for rainfall of each month. The outer loop will then; display the number of months, total inches of rainfall and the average rainfall per month for the whole time period (1 or 7 etc years).

Instead I get the below error. I've tried changing my code to make the counter variable i a string input so in some way I can get the incrementing number to be printing out.

I found a similar question at the below url though honestly it isn't making much sense to me as I don't understand .format in that answer?

[TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14856953/typeerror-input-expected-at-most-1-arguments-got-3)

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 45, in <module>
  File "python", line 25, in userInput
TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 2
```

Code

```
#//////MAIN PROGRAM START//////

#//////VARIABLE DECLARATION//////
years=0
timeTraveling=0
months=12
totalMonths=0
rainAverage=0

rainFall=0
#//////VARIABLE DECLARATION//////

#//////USER INPUT FUNCTION//////
def userInput():
    rainTotal=0
    print('This program will calculate the average rainfall over a period of years.')
    years=int(input("Please provide the number of years to calculate rainfall for."))
    for i in range(1, years + 1):
    #////////////////testing variable values correct////////////////
    #Placeholder
    #////////////////testing variable values correct////////////////
#//////USER INPUT FUNCTION//////
        for i in range(1, months + 1):
            rainTotal=0
            monthlyRainFall=int(input("Please provide the rainfall in inches for month number:", i))
            rainTotal = rainTotal + monthlyRainFall
            rainAverage=rainTotal/months
            totalMonths=years*months
            #//////testing variable <> value assignment/////
            print(rainTotal, 'inches of rain')
            #//////testing variable <> value assignment/////
#///////// python code references/////////////
#            print('Calculating for a total number of', totalMonths, 'months.')
#            print('Months\t\t\t' + 'Average Rainfall')        
#            print(rain, '\t\t\t\t\t', i)
#/////////format references/////////////
    print("Average Rainfall per month:", rainTotal/(years*12))
# after the inner loop runs the following should display

#   print('number of months
#   print('total inches of rainfall
#   print('average rainfall per month

#//////CALLING FUNCTION//////
userInput()
#//////CALLING FUNCTION//////
```

Comment: After using the code suggested monthlyRainFall=int(input("Please provide the rainfall in inches for month number: " + str(i)))  I now find that the average rainfall line of code in line 37 doesn't seem to be working correctly. If I enter the number of month that is displayed (1 for month 1 2 for month 2) there is a total of 78 inches of rain by the end though line 37 only outputs 1.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
monthlyRainFall=int(input("Please provide the rainfall in inches for month number:", i))
```

You sent `input()` two arguments: one is the string prompting the user, the other is `i`. Unlike `print()`, `input()` only takes one argument. Try this:

```
monthlyRainFall=int(input("Please provide the rainfall in inches for month number: " + str(i)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer/solution! So how is making the counter variable value (which would be an integer normally without that change) be fixed by converting it to a string via str(i)? Confusing.

Comment: When you separated the user prompt and `i` with a comma, you were sending two arguments to `input()`. It doesn't like that. Instead, you have to send a single string to `input()`, by simple string concatenation (e.g. `'hello ' + 'world'`). We put `str()` around `i` because `i` is a number, and you can't concatenate a string with a number, so the `str()` call converts `i` to a string.

Comment: Oh that's good to know I didn't know there were differences between using the command and plus sign when concatenating the lines. Interesting I will have to read up on that and keep it in mind. Thank you!

Comment: How would I get line 37 to output values from the inner loop?

Comment: Save those values to something like a `list`, and then `print()` that `list` however you like.

Answer (score 1):

you might want to make line 25:

```
monthlyRainFall=int(input("Please provide the rainfall in inches for month number:"+str(i) ))
```

if all you want is it to print out the value associated with i

Comment: Yes exactly what I was working to do there. Thank you very very much!