# Higher/lower game inputs

Tags: python, input

having trouble figuring out why my input for z isn't working. i type in my inputs for lower and upper, and then don't get the chance to enter any input for z.

**TypeError: input expected at most 1 argument, got 4**

```
print("Welcome to the higher/lower game, Bella!\n")

x = int(input("Enter Lower Bound: "))
y = int(input("Enter Upper Bound: "))
z = int(input("Great, now guess a number between", x, "and", y))
```

Comment: Duplicate: [TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14856953/4518341) or [Error - input expected at most 1 argument, got 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9969844/4518341)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have two strings and two variables inside your input for z.

Change the message to use string formatting so it is all in one piece:

```
'Great, now guess a number between {} and {}'.format(x, y)
```

Comment: Or, f-strings if you’d like it to be more concise.

Answer (score 0):

for this, I would suggest either using `.format` or an f string

for `.format`

```py
z = int(input('Great, now guess a number between {} and {}'.format(x, y)))
```

for an f string

```py
z = int(input(f"Great, now guess a number between {x} and {y}"))
```

I would personally use f string because I find it much simpler